# How can I dynamically define an instance hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slack-api

I created the following module:

```
module SlackHelper
  def alert_slack(message)
    notifier.ping.message
  end

  private

  def notifier(channel="default")
    @notifier[channel]||= Slack::Notifier.new ENV['SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL_' + channel]
  end
end
```

Previously this was written without channels, and it worked. The error that I get is:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@notifier ||= Hash.new{|hsh, k| hsh[k] = Slack::Notifier.new ENV['SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL_' + k]}
```

With this your hash is configured to automatically build the `Slack::Notifier` when you access a new key.

So you only have to do: `@notifier[channel]` and it gets instanciated.

So you can get rid of your private `notifier` method and do:

```
def alert_slack(message,channel='default')
  @notifier ||= Hash.new{|hsh, k| hsh[k] = Slack::Notifier.new ENV['SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL_' + k]}
  @notifier[channel].ping message
end
```

Comment: The biggest problem is where to put this definition in this case. Since OP is defining  module instance method, it means that this module will be included in some class - you need to set this instance variable on that class instances, which is not that easy task.

Comment: Then use the notifier method and do it inside, but for just one method this is useless

Comment: I made these changes:  
    `def alert_slack(message,channel='default')`  
  
    `@notifier[channel].ping message`  

Both this method and the one submitted by @BrioSatse work, I am not qualified to know which is better.

PS How the heck do I add line breaks to a comment?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def notifier(channel="default")
   @notifier ||= {}
   @notifier[channel] ||= Slack::Notifier.new ENV['SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL_' + channel]
end
```

Comment: I ended up using this method because I felt it was easier to read.